# Plot the graph and list the manufacturers in the order of fuel effciency of their vehicles

Tags: r

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 4) + xlab('Miles per Gallon') + ylab('Number of Cars') + 
   ggtitle('Distribution of Cars by Mileage')

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, this is what you want.

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(tidyverse)

# add column name on the car names
mtcars <- mutate(mtcars, car_name = row.names(mtcars))

# factor to make car in order by mpg
mtcars$car_name <- factor(mtcars$car_name, levels = mtcars$car_name[order(-mtcars$mpg)])

# plot by car and mpg
by_car <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(car_name, mpg, fill = car_name)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ xlab('Car Name') + ylab('Miles Per Gallon') + 
ggtitle('Distribution of Cars by Mileage') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: thank you for your attention, actually i run this code but its not working, actualy i'm not familiar with tidyverse library, kindly share me code only in ggplot2

Comment: i have another issue i will be very grateful if anybody can solve it,

Comment: #load data.
data(iris)
#Apply scaling.
scaled_df <- apply(iris, 2, scale)
# Calculate eigenvalues & eigenvectors.
arrests.cov <- cov(scaled_df)
arrests.eigen <- eigen(arrests.cov)
# Extract the first two sets of loadings and store them in the matrix phi.
(phi <- arrests.eigen$vectors[,1:2])
#change the sign to point eigenvectors in the positive direction.
phi <- -phi
row.names(phi) <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width" )
colnames(phi) <- c("PC1", "PC2")
phi

Comment: Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
Calls: apply -> FUN -> scale.default -> colMeans
Execution halted

Comment: You’d have to install the package tidyverse for the code to work. The tidyverse package just allowed me to clean up the data in this case I used the function, mutate. This allowed me to add a column name for the car names — that way then you can include this in your ggplot since you wanted it to be in order of mpg.